# $.ajax() vs $.getJSON() with YQL and cross domain requests

Tags: ajax, getjson, yql

I'm trying to execute a cross domain request for data from a wordpress blog using YQL. This is the code from my first attempt:

```
var g = {data:""}

function getWP() {

    var targeturl = "http://www.mysite.com";
    var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
        "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
        encodeURIComponent(targeturl)+
        "%22&format=xml'&callback=?";

     var successfunc = function(data) {
        if(data.results[0]){
            g.data = data.results[o];
        } else {
            var errormsg = '<p>Error: could not load the page.</p>';
            alert(errormsg);
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: successfunc
    });

}
```

When I tried this ajax call, the `data` object returned was an empty string. However, when I did this:

```
$.getJSON(url, successfunc);
```

the proper JSON object was returned. What is the difference between the two calls? And more importantly, why did only the second one work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that you are not specifying your data type or content type

Add

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: successfunc
});
```

to your ajax call

Comment: Since it's cross-domain, the datatype should be jsonp as mentioned by fahad below. Also, I would take the time to fully write out even a sim plified success function, in case a total novice later stumbles across the post. Otherwise, good answer and +1.

Answer (score 2):

**$.getJSON()** uses data type **json** while the **$.ajax()** doesn't. If you want to use standard **$.ajax()** you'll have to specify **datatype** explicitly. For cross-domail calls use datatype **jsonp** instead of **json**. But I think YQL works with json as well.

Comment: +1 for metntioning jsonp, but in future I would take the time to create a brief code sample.